# calculate between expiration date and the current date then return the remaining days in javascript

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

Good day, I want to calculate the remaining days between the expiration date and the current date but it seems that the return is not what I expected.

```
function expiryDate(date_string) {

    var date = date_string.split("/");
    var year = parseInt(date[2]);
    var day = parseInt(date[1]);
    var month = parseInt(date[0]);

var expiration = new Date(month,day,year);

   var d = new Date();
var curr_day = d.getDate();
var curr_month = d.getMonth()+1;
var curr_year = d.getFullYear();

var current_date = new Date(curr_month, curr_day, curr_year);

return (expiration - current_date) / (1000*60*60*24);
}
```

the code above will return the correct remaining days if the dates are the same for example.. the current date string was **05/01/2018** and the expiration is also the same and it will return 0, but when i move the expiration date to 1 day like 05/02/2018 the return is 28 days which is not correct.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: I'd recommend using a library like moment (see:https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/) and avoid concerning yourself with timezones/leap seconds/etc/etc.

Comment: Months are zero indexed, so `var month = date[0] - 1`. There is no need for *parseInt* or for a library. The difference in days is just `Math.round((expiration - current_date)/8.64e7)` and you're done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can difference between two dates using momentjs's [diff() function](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/)

Below is working code:

```js
function expiryDate(date_string) {
  var expiration = moment(date_string).format("YYYY-MM-DD");
  var current_date = moment().format("YYYY-MM-DD");
  var days = moment(expiration).diff(current_date, 'days');
  return days;
}

alert("Days remaining = " + expiryDate("2018-05-05"));
console.log("Days remaining = " + expiryDate("2018-05-05"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.1/moment.js"></script>
```

Comment: I've got Warning says Deprecation warning: value provided is not in a recognized RFC2822 or ISO format. moment construction falls back to js Date(), which is not reliable across all browsers and versions. Non RFC2822/ISO date formats are discouraged and will be removed in an upcoming major release.. is that okey?

Comment: @basaya yes this is what I mentioned in comment next to alert function. `"MM/DD/YYYY"` is not recommended date format. You should use some other formats or simply ignore it.

Comment: @basaya here are supported format. Use any of them : http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string/

Comment: @basaya for example:  just change format to "YYYY-MM-DD" and you will see no warning

Comment: @basaya for your convenience I have updated the date format. No warnings now.

Comment: I think your answer is the best answer for me. my project was already in this date format "MM/DD/YYYY" but string.replace() can fix that..  I will mark your answer as correct.. thanks for your help. :-)

Comment: An answer should not rely on a library that is neither tagged nor mentioned in the OP. You might suggest one as part of the answer thought. And parsing a string to a moment object, then formatting it as a string only to parse it again to a moment object is inefficient to say the least.

Answer (score 3):

As others have pointed out, months are zero indexed. Also, your method of zeroing the hours won't always work as expected because of daylight saving in some places. But rounding the result will remove DST effects.

There is no need for a library, your parse function and calculation can be be hugely simplified, you could easily remove another line from the following:

```js
/* @param {string} date_string - date in m/d/y format
** @returns {number} days between today and expiry
*/
function expiryDays(date_string) {
  var b = date_string.split(/\D/);
  var expiry = new Date(b[2],--b[0],b[1]);
  return Math.round((expiry - new Date().setHours(0,0,0,0)) / 8.64e7);
}

console.log(expiryDays('8/23/2018'));

// Or if you like obfuscated code
var expires = s=>Math.round((new Date(...(s.split(/\D/).reduce((a,v,i) => {a[(i+1)%3] = (i==0? v-1 : v);return a},[]))) - new Date().setHours(0,0,0,0))/8.64e7);

console.log(expires('8/23/2018'));
```

Comment: This is what I'm looking for, no library is the best answer for.  thank you sir. you are bit too late to mark your answer as a correct but your answer help me a lot..

Comment: @basaya—forgot to mention that the *expiryDays* function is compatible with every implementation in use.

Answer (score 1):

The `Date` object uses a zero-based month where January is 0, February is 1, etc. You seem to have tried in one place to compensate for that, but in the wrong way.

You need to fix this line like this:

```
var month = parseInt(date[0]) - 1;
```

And this line like this:

```
var curr_month = d.getMonth(); // No +1
```

Of course, using Moment.js, as suggested, is also a good idea, but I thought you might want to know how to get your own code working.

Comment: I changed the code and I tried your suggestion but its like just the same result as my problem.. if my expiration date is 05/02/2018 the return days remaining is 29 instead of 1 day... I want to know how it works just like you've said but i think the moment library is the best way...

Answer (score -1):

initially working with times is a lot of work sometimes, and often you will invest a lot of time, maybe the moment.js library may be a solution for you depending on the need, specifically the isBetween

follow the link below.

[moment.js](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/)

```
var a = moment([2007, 0, 29]);
var b = moment([2007, 0, 28]);
a.diff(b, 'days')
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but what exactly the result or return value of that example?

Comment: sorry, the result in this case will be in days, which in example returns 1